# How to add data dynamically in android

Tags: java, android

```
InboxData itemsData[] = { 
    new InboxData("Help", "Inbox", "my Date"),
    new InboxData("Delete", "Inbox", "my Date"),
    new InboxData("Cloud", "Inbox", "my Date"),
    new InboxData("Favorite", "Inbox", "my Date"),
    new InboxData("Like", "Inbox", "my Date"),
    new InboxData("Rating", "Inbox", "my Date")
};
```

It would be great someone help me to insert data programmically to InboxData itemsData[] inside loop inside following loop.

```
for(int i=0;i < helpjson.length();i++){ 
......
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I want to add data programmically to  InboxData itemsData[] inside loop.

Comment: @ppshein: have u tried it as `InboxData obj= new InboxData("Help", "Inbox", "my Date");itemsData[i]=obj;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int count = helpjson.length();
InboxData itemsData[] = new InboxData[count];
for(int i=0;i < count ;i++){ 
    itemsData[i] = new InboxData();
    //initialize your InboxData through data you get from helpjson.getXXX
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're trying to use an array rather than an array list to dynamically add things?

Arrays are built for lists that have a predetermined size (ie. an array for days of the week because there will always be 7), however array lists are built for taking in lists of various sizes (the number of cars a dealership sells in a month, it will always be different).

To implement just do:

```
ArrayList<InboxData> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int x = 0; x < helpjson.length(); x++){
    list.add(new InboxData(...));
}
```